# Communication between Android native and Trusted Web Activity(TWA)

Tags: java, android, intentfilter, trusted-web-activity, twa

I wrapped a Vue js web app using android to make it TWA(Trusted Web App).

Now I want to send firebase_token and other data from the Android part to the webapp in TWA. As all the Apis are on a web app and I don't want to call any API in Android.

In WebView we can send data from Android to the webapp using "WebViewController.evaluateJavascript()" but I don't know how can i send data from my Android(java) to web app.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass extra information to the Trusted Web Activity with query parameters.

If the parameter is the same across installs / launches, it can be added to the launchUrl itself.

If the parameter is more dynamic, you can implement your own LauncherActivity and override `getLaunchingUrl()` to add extra parameters to the URL.

This [article](https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity/query-parameters) contains details on how to implement both solutions.

It is not possible to establish a communication bridge between the web app and the Android app at runtime (like a [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) channel)

Comment: Is there any way of doing this after the application has already started? e.g I wanted to do that on a background service, so I can't use LauncherActivity in this case.